How can I rebase a series to a different base year?
I have three monthly data set for import prices.
First one --> Base year = 2003 (2003=100), data period: 2003 M1 - 2012 M12.
Second one --> Base year = 2010 (2010=100), data period: 2010 M1 - 2020 M12
Third one --> Base year = 2015 (2015 = 100), data period = 2013 M1 - 2024 M5.
I would like to create a data set coving all periods (between 2003 M1 and 2024 M5) with the same base year? How can I do this?
Thank you.
